# OpenID association problem

Tags: support, status-completed, openid, user-accounts, linked-accounts

I've recently [registered](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/6071/user6071) on Game Development with my Google OpenID, and I got the 100 rep for associating my accounts, but my name is *user6071* and the *About me* field is empty. I can't even copy my SO profile, it says an error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved.

There was a bug in validating user profile fields under some rare conditions.